# I want to delete the numbers but i show me an error

Tags: javascript

I want to delete the numbers but i show me an error.

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

let result = mix.map((a) => {
  return a.startsWith(typeof 1) ? a : "";
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I see it : main.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a.startsWith is not a function
    at main.js:4
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:3

Comment: please edit your post and add the above explanation (about the error log) to your post. It helps people a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over the array and create a new array of items that are not numbers.

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

let result = mix.filter(a => !Number(a));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to get the non-numeric values.

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];
let result = mix.filter(isNaN);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can also use `typeof` operator to check its type

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];
let result = mix.filter((a) => typeof a !== "number");
console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do as, It works because when you convert a number to a number using `Number` then only a number will be equal to itself, other than type `number` will be coerced to `NaN`.

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];
let result = mix.filter((a) => a !== Number(a));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way to "**delete**" specific elements from an array is with the [`array.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
you must also move in reverse so as not to disturb your index position

```js
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

for (let i = mix.length;i--;) if (!isNaN(mix[i])) mix.splice(i,1)

console.log( JSON.stringify( mix ))
```

Answer (score 0):

startsWith function determines whether a string begins with the characters of a specified string.

so first parameter is the characters to be searched for at the start of this string.

if you want delete all numbers in array, you can use array.filter

filter function creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

ex:

```
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "E", 4, "l", "z", "e", "r", 5, "o"];

let result = mix.filter(a => !Number(a));
```